# image (using create group) doesnot shows on device - While (as reference) works fine

Tags: localization, internationalization, ios-simulator, cocos2d-x, xcode7.3

My project uses localisation.

When i add images with "create group" option and do the following code - the images show up on simulator fine but not on the real device.

```
***Sample 1:***

MenuItemImage *leaderboard = MenuItemImage::create("btnLeaderboard.png", "btnLeaderboard.png", CC_CALLBACK_1(MenuLayer::onMenuItemClicked, this));
leaderboard->setTag(MenuItemTag::LEADERBOARD);
leaderboard->setPosition(-getContentSize().width/2 + (leaderboard->getContentSize().width * 0.75)/2, soundItem->getPositionY());
leaderboard->setScale(0.7);
items.pushBack(leaderboard);
menu *menu = Menu::createWithArray(items);
menu->setTag(212);
this->addChild(menu);
```

while if i add the images by "create folder references" option the images show up on both simulator & device but the **localisation** will be compromised and the code becomes like this :

```
***Sample 2:***

MenuItemImage *leaderboard = MenuItemImage::create("images/en.lproj/btnLeaderboard.png", "images/en.lproj/btnLeaderboard.png", CC_CALLBACK_1(MenuLayer::onMenuItemClicked, this));
leaderboard->setTag(MenuItemTag::LEADERBOARD);
leaderboard->setPosition(-getContentSize().width/2 + (leaderboard->getContentSize().width * 0.75)/2, soundItem->getPositionY());
leaderboard->setScale(0.7);
items.pushBack(leaderboard);
menu *menu = Menu::createWithArray(items);
menu->setTag(212);
this->addChild(menu);
```

but this isnt what i want.

**Is there some setup in project that i'm missing causing images to not show up on device with the "sample 1" ? or if i'm doing something wrong with the code itself?**

*p.s. If it's possible to keep image localisation with "folder by reference" option as well then that would be nice too.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folder references are the way to go.

You may want to consider adding a search path to the file utilities based on the current locale.

```
auto fileUtils = cocos2d::FileUtils::getInstance();
std::string localeImageDir = "en.lproj";
fileUtils->addSearchPath("images/" + locImageDir);
```

The above path will then be searched so:

```
auto explicit = Sprite::create("images/en.lproj/btnLeaderboard.png");
```

Becomes:

```
auto implicit = Sprite::create("btnLeaderboard.png");
```

The obvious limitation is that images must have identical names for each localisation.

If you need to change locale on the fly then you may want to use FileUtils::setSearchPaths() instead to override what was previously set.